# How to format complex json with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I've been trying to found a simple way to format complex json files and turn it into readable html content.

The goal is to generates a set of nested boxes (html tables) containing the information of my JSON file.

Here is a sample of my json:

```
{"badgeGroups":
[{"name":"labAccess0", "badges" : ["AAAAAAAAAA"]},
 {"name":"labAccess1", "badges" : ["1111111111","29006812B3"]}], 
"inputs":
    [{"name":"labDoorSecurityButton0", "state":false, "port":12}], 
"outputs":
    [{"name":"led0","equation":"labDoorSecurityButton0", "state":false,     "port":0,"type":"GENERIC", "inputs": ...
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's the actual question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm having trouble in finding a simple way to display it, and i'm pretty sure it's possible.
maybe it's possible to recursively display the keys and values?

Comment: Maybe write a recursive function that returns html of nested ul and li elements?

Comment: Do you want to "prettify" the JSON (so that it still looks like JSON) or do you want to just show the data it contains?

Comment: [DynaTables](https://www.dynatable.com/#existing-json) will solve your problem

Comment: I'm sorry, i realize i'm not very clear.
I want to organize the data contained by the json file, and just turn it into html list or table (something readable, not especially nice).

@rpax Thank you, it seems to be a good lead

Comment: You could take the display part of any javascript json editor [example](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends entirely on your expected output formatting.

For example, [bloopletech's json2html](https://github.com/bloopletech/json2html/tree/master) can parse arbitrary JSON input and a sample output can be seen [**over here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl4im.png).
If you want more customized formatting there's also [json2html jQuery plugin](http://json2html.com/).

All-in-all there are an infinite number of answers to your question as it's simply too broad.

Comment: The bloodpletech thing is definitely what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: I hate an accepted answer with -1

Answer (score -2):

```
function JSONtoXML(obj) {
  var s = "";
  var i=0;
  s = s + "<" + obj[0];
  var test = 0;
  for(i=1;i<obj.length;i++) {
    if(!(obj[i] instanceof Array) && !(typeof obj[i]==='string')) {
      var obje = obj[i];
      var k="";
      for(prp in obje) {
        k = k +" "+ prp + '="';
        k = k+ obje[prp] + '" ';
      }
      s = s+k;
    }
    else if(!(typeof obj[i]==='string')){
      if(test===0) {
        s = s+">";
        test++;
      }
      s = s + JSONtoXML(obj[i]);
    }
    else {
      if(test===0) {
        s = s+">";
        test++;
      }
      s = s +obj[i];
    }
  }
  if(test===0) {
    s = s+">";
    test++;
  }
  s = s+ "</" + obj[0] +">";
  return s;
}
```

This will do the job to convert json to xml.
if you want better readability try some json beautifier.